# SD card mount error

Tags: linux, mount

I m running into a mount problem with my SD Card. Linux returns this error message when I try to mount my SD:

```
mount -a
mount: special device /dev/mmcblk0p1 does not exist
```

Here is the entry in /etc/fstab:

```
# SD cards
/dev/mmcblk0p1    /sdcard1    auto    rw,auto,sync,flush,uid=1003,gid=1000
```

The directory /sdcard1 is present, however the device /dev/mmcblk0 and /dev/mmcblk0p1 does not exist.

I uploaded the output of my u-boot configuration, FDT and boot up sequence (output of dmesg) : http://www6.zippyshare.com/v/oG25SwZu/file.html

I m working with a TX48 COM with Linux 3.16 Kernel. I'm new to FDT and does not really know what to do to solve this problem.

I tested the baseboard and SD Card with a TX25 module running the old Linux 2.6.31 Kernel and was able to access the SD card.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Check your `dmesg` output for the actual device name.

Comment: It does not appear in the output of dmesg.

Comment: Run `udevadm monitor` and leave it running. Insert the SD card and wait a few seconds. Post the output from `udevadm` and the content of `/proc/partitions` afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have udevadm installed on this embedded system I will try to cross compile it.

Comment: I found the problem. A jumper on the baseboard was broken and was causing this problem. Thanks for your help